# Is it ok to throw an exception if Dictionary does not contain key

Tags: c#

I'm writing some code which gets properties from an object and uses them to populate a pdf.

The code I use to get items from my dictionary is below:

```
        public static int? GetYPrintCoord(string word)
        {
            // Try to get the result in the static Dictionary
            PrintCoord result;
            if (Dict.TryGetValue(word, out result))
            {
                return result.Y;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

where the dictionary looks like:

```
Dictionary<string, PrintCoord> Dict = new Dictionary<string, PrintCoord>();
```

The thing is I'm sick of checking for nulls when `GetYPrintCoord(string word)` is called. The fact is that if an item in the dictionary doesn't exist the whole pdf isn't worth generating because it will contain erroneous data. I was thinking instead of changing the method to:

```
    public static int GetYPrintCoord(string word)
    {
        // Try to get the result in the static Dictionary
        PrintCoord result;
        if (Dict.TryGetValue(word, out result))
        {
            return result.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

Is this bad practise/unadvisable? Throwing an exception and crashing would actually be a lot better in user terms because then at least the user wouldn't view an invalid pdf and possibly not knowing it's invalid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: that depends: should the key be in the dictionary? If it should then simply access (as shown below)

Comment: Are you a fan of writing more code than you need to? Why not just index into the dictionary and let *it* throw the `KeyNotFoundException`? Instead, you're using the alternative access mechanism (`TryGetValue`) that's designed to *avoid* throwing that exception because you don't want one to occur.

Comment: @MegaTron - I didn't know CodeReview existed. Good point.

Comment: This may be okay on Code Review, assuming **A)** the code works **and B)** the code is not hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel, this is the built-in behavior unless you need to do some logging before throwing the exception:

```
PrintCoord result = Dict[word]; // is equivalent to your code.
```

If the key is not found, an exception is thrown.

So basically you would use `TryGetValue` if you expect the key not to be found in the dictionary and you're ok with that. Second case would be if you don't want to use a `try...catch` and just use a simple if statement to handle the key not found case.

Comment: Cool this works. Was a dumb question. I haven't used dictionaries much before.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions represent, as the name suggest, exceptional cases.

If the fact that the key was not found in the dictionary denotes that something went wrong someplace else, that is, it is not something which *should* happen, then an exception might make sense.

That being said, if it is expected that sometimes the required key is not found, an exception might not make sense. What you can do, you could rename your `GetYPrintCoord` method as `TryGetYPrintCoord`. Then you make the method yield a boolean, `True` if the key was found, `False` if otherwise and use the `out` keyword to pass back the value in the dictionary.